# Table with unique drop down combination for each row

Tags: javascript, html-select

I am having a table where there is two drop down drop-1 and drop-2. So I want to have drop-1 and drop-2 combination as unique.

I tried to create a new object and store that value in that but did not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>Table</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>DD 1</th>
    <th>DD 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="D1">
        <option value="fan">Fan</option>
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="cycle">Cycle</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><select name="D2">
        <option value="electricity">Electricity</option>
        <option value="petrol">Petrol</option>
        <option value="tube">Tube</option>
        <option value="load">Load</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="D1">
        <option value="fan">Fan</option>
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="cycle">Cycle</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><select name="D2">
        <option value="electricity">Electricity</option>
        <option value="petrol">Petrol</option>
        <option value="tube">Tube</option>
        <option value="load">Load</option>
        </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><select name="D1">
        <option value="fan">Fan</option>
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="cycle">Cycle</option>
        <option value="truck">Truck</option>
        </select></td>
    <td><select name="D2">
        <option value="electricity">Electricity</option>
        <option value="petrol">Petrol</option>
        <option value="tube">Tube</option>
        <option value="load">Load</option>
        </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Need some clarity of thoughts how to achieve that need some suggestion the best possible way to do it if possible with an example

Comment: why do you have these dropdowns repeating? where do you want to render the combination? in D3 somewhere?

Comment: That is one set of for me. Each row is one set for me. There are other columns also I just asked for this two. As it should be an unique one.

Comment: yes. Do you want to combine them to make a new dropdown? or do you want their options to not repeat?

Comment: no I don't want any new dropdown just the row need unique. Means one row one combination. Suppose in one dropdown I had an array of 4 object as [{name : 'a',id:1},{name : 'b',id:2},{name : 'c',id:3},{name : 'd',id:4}] and in second dropdown there is another  array with 3 object as [{name : 'e',id:1},{name : 'f',id:2},{name : 'g',id:3}]. Now for every row I want one value from array one as 'a' and another value from another array as 'e'. So that is a unique combination there should not be another combination as 'a' from one column and 'e'  from another column.

Comment: so, there should be no repeating values in both dropdowns ? right? do you want to have it in a list of javascript object?  what output do you expect?

Comment: Correct,it will be two separate object with no relationship at the output but while selecting from UI there should be restriction that is the output.